# Load a script only once

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to load a script only once when the user visits (a success page).

My idea was to write something with local storage:

```
if ( localStorage.getItem("beenHere")) {
    localStorage.setItem('beenHere', 1);
    window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
        fathom.trackGoal('XXX', {{ order.totalPrice * 100 }});
    });
}
```

But that doesnt work because `load` is always loaded. How would I approach that?

Comment: so, if `localStorage.getItem("beenHere")` is "truthy" ... set it to 1 (truthy) and do the thing .... therefore, it only executes `fathom.trackGoal('XXX', {{ order.totalPrice * 100 }});` when `localStorage.getItem("beenHere"))` is truthy

Comment: Third option for addEventListener  `{ once: true }`

Comment: @MikitaMelnikau Oh, very elegant. Thank you. So local storage isn't necessary at all?! Can you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be this instead? Initially `localStorage.getItem("beenHere")` is null so it evaluates to false, therefore the code inside the if condition never runs and `beenHere` is never set to 1.

```
if (!localStorage.getItem("beenHere")) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `{ once: true }` as a third option for addEventListener